# How to use information from created function to get added in new <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to make a form where people can input information, and the info will then show up in a new div afterwards within a paragraph tag.

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <input   type="text" id="userInput">
           <input    type="submit" onclick="addParagraphs()"> <!-- button -->
                            </form>
```

The way I'm currently trying to make it work is by having a function that looks at what information gets filled out, this is done by;

```
function othername() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
}.
```

This way I am able to "save" the info, but my issue comes when I have to make it appear I a paragraph later on. I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to recall this stored information. The way I have tried is the following:

```
function addParagraphs()
     {
         var para = document.createElement("p");
         var node = document.createTextNode(othername());
         para.appendChild(node);
         var element = document.getElementById("sizeValgt");
         element.appendChild(para);
      }
```

The "sizeValgt" is the id for the new div where the paragraph tag, is gonna be created when filling out the information.

This might be a little confusing, but I hope some people are able to understand what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: "I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to recall this stored information." — You'd have to store it somewhere in the first place to do that. At the moment you are shoving it in a local variable, doing nothing with it, then letting it be garbage collected when the function ends.

Comment: use innerHTML to write data to p tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code

- **First:** : you are not returning value from your `othername` function
- **Second**:  you are not adding this value in `p` tag

```js
function othername() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    return input;
}

function addParagraphs(){
  var para=document.getElementById("test");
  if(para==null){
     para = document.createElement("p");
     para.id="test";
  }
  para.innerText=othername();
  var element = document.getElementById("sizeValgt");
  element.appendChild(para);
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <input   type="text" id="userInput">
           <input    type="submit" onclick="addParagraphs()"> <!-- button -->
                            </form>
                            <div id="sizeValgt"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! This works! 
guess i should take some time to read i a bit about returning values? 
You are a champ thou!

Comment: Great! Happy to help

Comment: Bonus question! - is there a way to make it the filled out text replace itself, insted of creating more new p tags, if i want to change my "answer/filled out" info.

Comment: Yes, you can do that easily. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply in jquery. Example:

**HTML**

```
  <input type="text" id="uinput"/>
  <input type="submit" id="usubmit"/>
  <p id="dis"></p>
```

**Jquery**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#usubmit').click(function(){
  var utext= $('#uinput').val();
  $('#dis').html(utext);
  });
  });
```